# On the dual nature between interior and closure with regards to complements.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am writing some lecture notes (Topology) from my professors notes, however, he (typically) does not prove much...or will only prove part of a proposition, lemma, problem, ...etc. Furthermore, in my notes I do want full proofs, moreover, I would like some nice proofs! Below is the proposition (I think, maybe someone can confirm if it should be something else!) and my proof. Hopefully, someone can fix and/or critique my proof!

**Proposition:** Let $(\mathbb{X}, \tau)$ be a Topological Space and $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$, then the following holds $(A^o)^c = \overline{(A^c)}$.

(My attempted) **Proof:** Let $x \in (A^o)^c$. Then $x \notin A^o$, meaning, $\forall U_x \in \tau: x \in U_x \not\subseteq A$. However, this implies that $\forall U_x \in \tau$, $x \in U_x: U_x \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$. Therefore, we can conclude that $x \in \overline{A^c}$, hence, the followings holds $(A^o)^c \subseteq \overline{A^c}$. Now, suppose $x \in \overline{(A^c)}$. Then $\forall U_x \in \tau$, $x \in U_x: U_x \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$. However, this implies that $\forall U_x \in \tau$, $x \in U_x: U_x \not\subseteq A$. In other words, $x \not\in A^o$, i.e. $x \in (A^o)^c$, hence, the followings holds $\overline{A^c} \subseteq (A^o)^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof works fine. It's based on the fact that the interior is the set of interior points, and the closure the set of adherent points. We can also use a minimaliy/maximality argument:

$A^\circ \subseteq A$ is an open, so $A^\complement \subseteq (A^\circ)^\complement$ and the right hand side is closed. The closure of a set is the minimal closed superset, so $\overline{A^\complement} \subseteq (A^\circ)^\complement$, showing one inclusion.

OTOH, $A^\complement \subseteq \overline{A^\complement}$ and so $\overline{A^\complement}^\complement \subseteq  \overline{A^\complement}^\complement = A$ and the left hand set is open so by maximality of the interior: $\overline{A^\complement}^\complement \subseteq A^\circ$ and taking complements again we get $(A^\circ)^\complement \subseteq \overline{A^\complement}$, which is the other inclusion.